# Need help in tokenizing a text file and storing in vector

Tags: c++, vector, sqlite

I am reading from a text file that looks like this:

```
1|Pink Floyd
2|Genesis
3|Einaudi
4|Melanie C
```

I have a vector artistVector to store the ID (integer), and the Artist Name char(100).

I am trying to parse the text file and store the parsed ID and Name like this:

```
artistVector[0] = 1
artistVector[1] = Pink Floyd
artistVector[2] = 2
artistVector[3] = Genesis
artistVector[4] = 4
artistVector[5] = Einaudi
artistVector[6] = 6
artistVector[7] = Melanie C
```

But for some reason, my code after Pink Floyd is not working with my sqlite insert record function.

```
static vector<string> readFile(vector<string> artVec, ifstream &iFile) //Read the file into the vector function definition
{
vector<string> vector;
string line;
if (iFile.is_open()) {
    while (!iFile.eof()) {
        // read an item using | as a delimiter
        //getline(artist, line, '|');
        getline(iFile, line, '|');
        vector.push_back(line);

        getline(iFile, line, '\n');
        vector.push_back(line);
        getline(iFile, line, '\n');
        vector.push_back(line);
    }
}
else {
    cout << "Unable to open file";
}
return vector;
}

int main() {

vector<string> artistVector;
ifstream artistFile("artist.txt"); //Input file

artistVector = readFile(artistVector, artistFile);
std::string sqlArtistInsert[8];

for (int i = 0; i < artistVector.size(); i++) {
    sqlArtistInsert[i] = artistVector[i];
}
cout << sqlArtistInsert[0] << endl;
cout << sqlArtistInsert[1] << endl;
cout << sqlArtistInsert[2] << endl;



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

My output looks like this:

```
1
Pink Floyd

2
```

Notice the white space between Pink Floyd and 2? aka sqlArtistInsert[1] & sqlArtistInsert[2]

please take a look at my code below and any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Problems I see:

**Problems in `while` loop**

```
while (!iFile.eof()) {
    // read an item using | as a delimiter
    //getline(artist, line, '|');
    getline(iFile, line, '|');
    vector.push_back(line);

    getline(iFile, line, '\n');
    vector.push_back(line);
    getline(iFile, line, '\n');
    vector.push_back(line);
}
```

The last call to `getline` will read an additional line of text. When the loop is executed the first time,

`line` will be assigned `"1"` in the first call to `getline`.
`line` will be assigned `"Pink Floyd"` in the second call to `getline`.
`line` will be assigned `"2|Genesis"` in the third call to `getline`.

I am sure that is not your intention. Remove the third call to `getline` in the loop.

The other problem is that you will end up storing more items in `vector` than there are in the file. See [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) for a more in-depth explanation. Your loop needs to be something like:

```
  while (getline(iFile, line, '|')) {
     vector.push_back(line);

     getline(iFile, line, '\n');
     vector.push_back(line);
  }
```

**Insufficient size of `sqlArtistInsert` in `main`**

With your current size of `8`, the program was using memory beyond the valid limits due to the problems in the `while` loop. With the `while` loop fixed, that should not be a problem any more.

To be safe, I would use:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < artistVector.size() && i < 8; i++) {
   sqlArtistInsert[i] = artistVector[i];
}
```